# Kubernetes update changes static+reserved external IPs for nodes in Google Cloud

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have three nodes in my google container cluster.

Everytime i perform a kubernetes update through the web-ui on the cluster in Google Container Engine.

[image: Google container cluster update]

My external IP's change, and i have to manually assign the previous IP on all three instances in Google Cloud Console.

These are reserved static external IP set up using the following guide.

[Reserving a static external IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-ip-addresses#reserve_new_static)

Has anyone run into the same problem? Starting to think this is a bug.

Perhaps you can set up the same static outbound external IP for all the instances to use, but i cannot find any information on how to do so, that would be a solution as long as it persists through updates, otherwise we've got the same issue.

It's only updates that cause this, not restarts.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by `google compute cloud cluster` means? Do you mean container engine cluster? Also can you define what `perform a kubernetes update` means? What are you updating? Are you using an Ingress or Service resource associated to your external IP? How are you using the external IP on your application? Need more details...

Comment: Sorry for slight misinformation, updated my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same problem as you. We found some solutions.

- [KubeIP](https://github.com/doitintl/kubeIP) - But this needed a cluster 1.10 or higher. Ours is 1.8
- NAT - At GCP documentation they talk about this method. It was too complex for me.

**Our Solution**
We followed the [documentation for assign IP addresses on GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#IP_assign). Used the command line.
Using this method, we didn't have any problems so far. I don't know the risks for it yet. If anyone has an idea, it would be good.

We basically just ran:

```
gcloud compute instances delete-access-config [INSTANCE_NAME]  --access-config-name [CONFIG_NAME]
gcloud compute instances add-access-config [INSTANCE_NAME] --access-config-name "external-nat-static" --address [IP_ADDRESS]
```

If anyone have any feedback on this solution. Please give it to us.
@Ahmet Alp Balkan - Google

Comment: Just adding one note... we've been using this approchh for 3 months now, and no problems so far.

Answer (score 2):

You should not rely on the IP addresses of each individual node. Instances can come and go (especially when you use [Cluster Autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/cluster-autoscaler)), and their IP addresses can change.

You should always be exposing your applications with [Service](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/) or [Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) and IP addresses of the load balancers created with these resources do not change between upgrades. Further you can convert IP address on a load balancer to a static (reserved) IP address.

I see that you're assigning static IP addresses to your nodes. I don't see any reason to do that. When you expose your services with Service/Ingress resources, you can associate a static external IP to them.

See this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#step_5_optional_configuring_a_static_ip_address

Comment: We're using multiple external services that require whitelisted ips, that's why we need static ips.

Comment: Many use a static IP on a few of their nodes for ingress. A LoadBalancer is minimum $18 or so per month while static IPs are free when assigned to an instance. With proper tooling it's a good fit for many use cases. (Obviously there are drawbacks.)

Comment: We need to reach through a firewall from our instances, and have the same issue.  Scaling isn't a concern, but upgrade and resilience put this method on my list of matters to improve.